# Run function when selecting a new item in a QComboBox

Tags: python, qcombobox

I have a QComboBox with a few items in it, and I want to run a function when the user selects a new item, different from the current one.

The basic code (without including the items) is..

```
categories_combo = gui.QComboBox()
categories_combo.connect("currentIndexChanged()", lambda: doSomething())

def doSomething():
    print "it's working"
```

The general idea works fine for QPushButton's, eg.

```
my_button.connect("clicked()", lambda: doSomething())
```

But I can't get anything out of the QComboBox.

Cheers,
ST

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put an (int)

```
categories_combo.connect("currentIndexChanged(int)", lambda: update())
```